# artistWithURI exception when trying to obtain SPTArtist object and associated cover artwork

Tags: ios, spotify

I am trying to obtain the cover artwork image with Spotify iOS SDK. As I understand the API, there are convenience methods of the SPTArtist object for the smallest and largest SPTImage. When the audioStreaming controller delegate fires at the start of a new track, it provides track metadata for the current song that includes the SPTAudioStreamingMetadataArtistURI. I am trying to use this URI to obtain the SPTArtist object for this song in the following way:

```
-(void)audioStreaming:(SPTAudioStreamingController *)audioStreaming didChangeToTrack:(NSDictionary *)trackMetadata {
    [SPTArtist artistWithURI:trackMetadata[SPTAudioStreamingMetadataArtistURI] session:[SpotifySettingsHelper session] callback:^(NSError *error, id object) {
        ...
        // asynchronously obtain the image
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:artist.largestImage.imageURL options:0 error:&error];
        ...
    }];
}
```

The [SPTArtist artistWithURI:session:callback] call is crashing with the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString absoluteString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9ed0ebe4d0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d43ff35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010d0d8bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d44704d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d39f27c ___forwarding___ + 988
4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d39ee18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   MyGreatApp                        0x000000010a08a053 __52+[SPTRequest requestItemAtURI:withSession:callback:]_block_invoke + 160
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d919ba6 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d9377f4 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d92215d _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1097
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d9235d9 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 111
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010dcbb6cb _pthread_wqthread + 729
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010dcb94a1 start_wqthread + 13
```

)

What is wrong with this approach? If this is not the proper way, how should I be obtaining the artwork?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're passing an `NSString` to an API that wants an `NSURL`. Check what `trackMetadata[SPTAudioStreamingMetadataArtistURI]` returns — if it's an `NSString`, use `[NSURL urlWithString:]` to convert it.

Also, in your code you write `// asynchronously obtain the image` then perform a synchronous task. That'll block your main thread for a large amount of time.

Comment: It contains a URI in the form of spotify:* (spotify:artist:70kkdajctXSbqSMJbQO424). This is what the API describes as the required input (see https://developer.spotify.com/ios-sdk-docs/Documents/Classes/SPTArtist.html#//api/name/artistWithURI:session:callback:). With respect to you comment on the asynchronous task, I was lazy and did not put all the code in for that (just trying to give an idea of what I was going to do with the SPTArtist object once I received it). I tried your suggestion anyway. Doesn't crash, but return object is nil (and error is nil). Any other thoughts?

Comment: Oops. xcode was showing the object as being nil, but then I printed the object with po object. It did work. I guess I was being too literal with the API comments. Your suggestion worked. Thanks.